# .NET Core сборка IL кода

Tags: .net, .net-core, cil

Есть масса кода написанного на IL, который требуется перевести на рельсы .NET Core, однако, при чтении документации выяснилось, что ilasm.exe там не предусмотрен. Вроде есть что-то в NuGet, но тянуть оттуда возможности нет, так как компьютер, на котором планируется проводить сборку изолирован от интернета. Бегать же с флешкой что-то загружать тоже не айс. Но в виду того, что классы для генерации IL кода и последующего создания из него сборок есть в самой платформе, подумал набросать свой собственный небольшой компилятор. Однако к каким классам обратиться, инфы нигде не нашел. Возможно искал плохо, а потому прошу помочь либо кодом, либо ссылками.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть масса кода написанного на IL, который требуется перевести на рельсы .NET Core, однако, при чтении документации выяснилось, что ilasm.exe там не предусмотрен.

Это так. Однако, в .NET Core, начиная с версии 2.0, поддерживается запуск сборок, скомпилированных под .NET Framework (естественно, они должны использовать только то, что есть в .NET Core, иначе будет ошибка во время выполнения). Так что эта проблема может быть и не очень критична.

> Вроде есть что-то в NuGet, но тянуть оттуда возможности нет, так как компьютер, на котором планируется проводить сборку изолирован от интернета. Бегать же с флешкой что-то загружать тоже не айс.

Ну так если нельзя ни скачивать с интернета, ни приносить на флешке, как вообще вести разработку под .NET Core? Для этого нужен как минимум .NET Core SDK, который желательно иногда обновлять.

> Но в виду того, что классы для генерации IL кода и последующего создания из него сборок есть в самой платформе, подумал набросать свой собственный небольшой компилятор. Однако к каким классам обратиться, инфы нигде не нашел.

[System.Reflection.Emit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit) ?

---

**Дополнение.** Сборка IL для .NET Core возможна при использовании специального SDK [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.IL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.IL). Ранее он использовался только внутренне в репозитории CoreCLR, но теперь его выложили в общую галерею NuGet. Чтобы его использовать, нужно добавить в каталог с проектом файл global.json подобного содержания (версию по необходимости поменять):

```
{  
  "msbuild-sdks": {    
    "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.IL": "5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Затем нужно создать файл .ilproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.IL">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
</Project>
```

После этого можно добавлять в каталог файлы с расширением .il, они автоматически подхватятся для сборки. Сборка делается командой dotnet build (VS не поддерживается). Полный пример проекта можно посмотреть здесь: https://github.com/MSDN-WhiteKnight/CodeSamples/tree/master/IL

Источник: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11411#issuecomment-436427961